How to find endpoint for an event grid "partner" topic
I would like to read the events in an event grid from a .net core console app.  I'm following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/messaging.eventgrid-readme?view=azure-dotnet
The article indicates that I need to find the endpoint for my grid.  But the instructions are for a rgular topic, not a partner topic.
In my case, I created an MS Graph subscription that will trigger anytime changes are made in Entra Groups.
This is the command I run to get all details for this partner topic: (the name of the topic is "yourPartnerTopic")
 az eventgrid partner topic show --ids /subscriptions/[mysubscription]/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-WIDGETS/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/partnerTopics/yourPartnerTopic

And these are the results I see in the az cli:
{
  "activationState": "Activated",
  "eventTypeInfo": null,
  "expirationTimeIfNotActivatedUtc": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/mysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup-WDIGETS/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/partnerTopics/yourPartnerTopic",
  "identity": null,
  "location": "canadacentral",
  "messageForActivation": null,
  "name": "yourPartnerTopic",
  "partnerRegistrationImmutableId": "123123-707c-436d-bbbb-123123",
  "partnerTopicFriendlyDescription": null,
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "resourceGroup": "DefaultResourceGroup-WIDGETS",
  "source": "tenant_mytenantId",
  "systemData": null,
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/partnerTopics"
}
me@my-iMac eventgridOnPremListener % 

There is no "endpoint" returned.  And I've checked the gui too.  IN azure portal's overview section for this topic, I do not see any endpoint.
So I have to ask, are you able to connect to a partner topic from .net apps?  or just custom topics?
Any tips would be appreciated.

So far I know you have to subscribe partner event and streamline to evenhub, have you tried on this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/subscribe-to-partner-events

Partner topics is completely different from normal/Custom topics in Event Grids. Partner Topics are connected with Micorsft Garph Api, Auth) , SAP and etc:


How to find endpoint for an event grid "partner" topic

These do not have endpoints as Custom topics.

The article indicates that I need to find the endpoint for my grid. But the instructions are for a rgular topic, not a partner topic.

Yes, as the article is about Custom Topics and not the Partner topics
